# What are these gaps called? Where to set them up?

Tags: leaflet, gis, openstreetmap, osrm

I worked whith own OSRM server and Leaflet Routing Mashine.

There was a problem building the route:
[image]

I am building a route for cars( car.lua profile). OSRM from the starting point leads through the forest to a longer route.
But the road passes right through the start point. This is highway = tertiary. 
Why OSRM behaves this way?
 What is the name of this "forest gap"?
 Where to read about it?
 
What settings are responsible for this: profile.lua or server request?

In profile car.lua:
[image: profile car.lua:]

Comment: Could it be that the tertiary road next to the start point is not properly connected to the rest of the road network? That would explain why OSRM can't use it and chooses to "jump" to the next road that is part of the road network.

Comment: @scai At first I thought so too. That highway = tertiary is not connected to the road network. But in profile car.lua there is highway = tertiary.

Comment: I'm not talking about car.lua but about the road network in OSM or your database, respectively. Check any online OSM router if it shows the same problems.